No Http trigger found while deploying the azure durable function
I have created an Azure Durable Function that successfully extracts data from an API and loads it into a PostgreSQL database. Locally, everything works fine. However, upon deployment to an Azure Function App using an App Service Plan, I encounter the error message "No HTTP triggers found."
Here are some details about my setup:
I am using an App Service Plan for hosting.
The Durable Function is supposed to be triggered via HTTP.
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
from fluxx_extraction import data_extractor

myApp = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

# An HTTP-Triggered Function with a Durable Functions Client binding
@myApp.route(route="orchestrators/{functionName}")
@myApp.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def Http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest, client):
    function_name = req.route_params.get('functionName')
    instance_id = await client.start_new(function_name)
    response = client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return response

# Orchestrator
@myApp.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def hello_orchestrator(context):
    result1 = yield context.call_activity("activity_function")

    return result1

# Activity
@myApp.activity_trigger(input_name="name")
def activity_function(city: str):

    data_extractor()

    return "extraction completed"

data_extractor.py:
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import asyncpg
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import logging
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, wait_fixed, RetryError

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Global variables to track API rate limiting
REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE = 400

REQUESTS_INTERVAL = 60 / REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE  # Interval between requests in seconds
RECORDS_PER_PAGE = 100  # Number of records per page

# Semaphore to control concurrent API requests
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE // 60)  # Number of concurrent requests per second

async def fetch_access_token(api_credentials):
    token_url = "https://appi.fluxx.io/oauth/token"
    try:
        response = requests.post(token_url, data=api_credentials, timeout=60)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()['access_token']
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to fetch access token: {e}")
        return None

@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(5), wait=wait_fixed(60))
async def fetch_data_from_api(session, url, headers, table_name, cols_param):
    async with semaphore:
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(REQUESTS_INTERVAL)  # Ensure the interval between requests
            async with session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=60) as response:
                if response.status == 429:
                    # Handle rate limiting
                    retry_after = int(response.headers.get('Retry-After', 60))
                    logging.info(f"Rate limited. Retrying after {retry_after} seconds.")
                    await asyncio.sleep(retry_after)
                    raise Exception("Rate limit reached")
                response.raise_for_status()
                data = await response.json()
                total_pages = data.get('total_pages', 1)
                records = data.get('records', {})
                all_records = records.get(table_name, [])
                tasks = [
                    fetch_paginated_data(session, f"{url}&page={page}", headers, table_name)
                    for page in range(2, total_pages + 1)
                ]
                paginated_results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                for result in paginated_results:
                    if result:
                        all_records.extend(result)
                return all_records
        except (aiohttp.ClientError, asyncio.TimeoutError) as e:
            logging.error(f"Failed to fetch data from API: {e}")
            raise

@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(5), wait=wait_fixed(60))
async def fetch_paginated_data(session, url, headers, table_name):
    async with semaphore:
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(REQUESTS_INTERVAL)  # Ensure the interval between requests
            async with session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=60) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                data = await response.json()
                records = data.get('records', {}).get(table_name, [])
                return records
        except (aiohttp.ClientError, asyncio.TimeoutError) as e:
            logging.error(f"Failed to fetch paginated data for {url}: {e}")
            raise

def truncate_table(engine, table_name):
    try:
        with engine.connect() as connection:
            connection.execute(text(f'TRUNCATE TABLE fluxx.{table_name} RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE'))
            connection.commit()  # Ensure the transaction is committed
            logging.info(f"Table {table_name} truncated successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred while truncating {table_name} table: {e}")

def insert_data_to_postgres_sync(engine, table_name, column_names, data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)

    if table_name == 'grant_request':
        current_utc_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
        df['sync_at'] = current_utc_time  # Add current local time for 'grant_request' table

    try:
        # Use DataFrame.to_sql() to insert data into PostgreSQL table
        df.to_sql(table_name, engine, schema='fluxx', if_exists='append', index=False)
        logging.info(f"Data inserted into {table_name} successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred while inserting data into {table_name} table: {e}")

async def process_table(session, url, headers, table_name, column_names, engine):
    try:
        data = await fetch_data_from_api(session, url, headers, table_name, column_names)
        if data is None:
            logging.error(f"Failed to fetch data for {table_name}. Skipping to next table.")
            return
        # Truncate the table before inserting new data
        truncate_table(engine, table_name)
        # Insert data
        insert_data_to_postgres_sync(engine, table_name, column_names, data)
    except RetryError:
        logging.error(f"Failed to fetch data for {table_name} after multiple retries. Skipping to next table.")

async def extractor():
    api_credentials = {
        "grant_type": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }

    access_token = await fetch_access_token(api_credentials)
    if not access_token:
        logging.error("No access token retrieved, exiting.")
        return

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }

    # Define your database configuration here
    db_config = {
        "database": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "user": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "host": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "port": "x"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    }

    # Create the synchronous SQLAlchemy engine
    db_url_sync = f"postgresql://{db_config['user']}:{db_config['password']}@{db_config['host']}:{db_config['port']}/{db_config['database']}"
    sync_engine = create_engine(db_url_sync)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with asyncpg.create_pool(**db_config) as pool:
            async with pool.acquire() as conn:
                async with conn.transaction():
                    table_names_query = "SELECT table_name, array_agg(column_name) FROM column_metadata GROUP BY table_name"
                    rows = await conn.fetch(table_names_query)

            for row in rows:
                table_name, column_names = row['table_name'], row['array_agg']
                cols_param = ','.join([f'"{col}"' for col in column_names])
                url = f"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/rest/v2/{table_name}?cols=[{cols_param}]&per_page={RECORDS_PER_PAGE}"
                await process_table(session, url, headers, table_name, column_names, sync_engine)



def data_extractor():
    asyncio.run(extractor())
    return "extraction is successfull"

local.settings.json
    {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}

host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}

requirement.txt:
azure-functions
azure-functions-durable
pandas
requests
sqlalchemy
psycopg2-binary
asyncio
aiohttp
asyncpg
tenacity


A lot can happen during deployment and is linked to a couple of files: host.json and the requirements.txt you create.
We would need to see those files in order to help

i have added the required files

What about the requirements.txt file ?

I have added, please check once

asyncio is a library listed as pre-installed for Python, at least for 3.11.
Therefore you should not declare it in your requirements.txt, as it would cause a conflict on Azure side. Source: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/
Source MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#preinstalled-libraries

@nikhil, please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

Run the function locally and check if you can sync the trigger locally before deploying to Azure.
I can see you have named data_extractor.py instead of fluxx_extraction.py, but importing using the code from fluxx_extraction import data_extractor in function_app.py.
Update the file name to fluxx_extraction.py instead of data_extractor.py

I have used your code in my Durable Azure function and could deploy to Azure function app.

Local Response:


Deployed the function to Azure function app using function core tools with command func azure functionapp publish <functionapp_name>:

(.venv) C:\Users\uname\durablefn>func azure functionapp publish kpfn
Getting site publishing info...
[2024-07-02T07:43:24.646Z] Starting the function app deployment...
Removing WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING app setting.
Removing WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE app setting.
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Uploading 11.95 MB [##############################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait...
Updating submodules.

// Removed few logs

Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE placeholder blob scm-latest-kpfn.zip located
Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...
Resetting all workers for kpfn.azurewebsites.net
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
[2024-07-02T07:47:08.806Z] Syncing triggers...
Functions in kpfn:
    hello - [activityTrigger]

    hello_orchestrator - [orchestrationTrigger]

    http_start - [httpTrigger]
        Invoke url: https://kpfn.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/{functionname}

Portal:

